# Lucene 4.4: Update particular term's frequency in a document field without re-indexing the whole field

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, recommendation-engine

I use Lucene 4.4 to store users' reading profiles which are represented by word vectors and are stored in a single document field. These profiles are frequently modified: some terms counts need to be incremented or decremented. Is there a better way to update term frequencies than loading the whole document term vector, modifying it and then indexing again?

Answer (score 2):

No, to update a document in Lucene, you must reindex the document.  The process can be simplified using a call to [updateDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20java.lang.Iterable%29), but this doesn't simplify the operation on the backend.  It still must delete the old document, and index a new one.

Comment: You confirmed my findings. Looks like lucene is not the best choice for storing frequently modified documents.